# Read object parameter in route parameter

Tags: angular

I'm trying to send the object parameter. from list component.

```
editStudent(student)
   {
    this.router.navigate(['/addStudent', student]); 
   }
```

studentModel object is like:

```
addressModel = new AddressClass("", "", "");
  studentModel = new StudentClass(0,"", "", "", "", "", true, "", this.addressModel)
```

I'm trying to read the student object on some other component:

```
ngOnInit() {      
    this.studentModel = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('stud'); 
  }
```

Comment: Route path is like: {path:'addStudent/:stud', component : AddStudentComponent},

Comment: I just want to read the complete set of object in a single go through route.snapshot.

Comment: I think you are mixing concepts. You need to pass some specific value in a part of your route. Not a complex object. Maybe you need change a bit your logic.

Comment: Route parameters end up in the url. You can't put en entire object in the url. Put the ID of the user, and get back the student from the backend in the addStudent route.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-data-to-route/). It can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The approach would be to :-

```
editStudent(student)
{
 this.router.navigate(['/addStudent', {'data' : JSON.stringify(student)}]); 
}

ngOnInit() {      
this.studentModel = JSON.parse(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('data')); 
}
```